# socket hang up node 0.8.17

Tags: node.js

I am getting a "socket hang up" error while doing a post request. I am not able to resolve it.

```
  sparqlQ = getSPARQLPrefix() + query_string;
  console.log(sparqlQ)
  var options = {
    host: process.env['SESAME_HOST'],
    port: process.env['SESAME_PORT'],
    method: 'POST',
    path:
      '/openrdf-sesame/repositories/myReo?update=' +
      encodeURIComponent(sparqlQ) +
      '&content-type=application/sparql-results+json',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept': 'application/sparql-results+json',
    },
  };

  var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    var data = "";
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
      data += chunk;
    });
    res.on('error', function (error) {
      console.log(error)
    });
    res.on('end', function () {
       console.log(data)
       req.end();
       callback(null);
    });
  }).on('error', function(e) {
    console.alert("Error getting sesame response [%s]", e.message);
    req.end();
    callback(e.message);
    return
  });
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Comment: Upgrade your node version. That's all you need to do.

Comment: Or listen for errors on req.socket

Comment: if I use req.socket('error', ..)...then it says TypeError: Object #<ClientRequest> has no method 'socket'

Comment: @JonathanOng - do you have a reference to a bug/issue that you could post here?

Answer (score 1):

Two things to mention here.

---

**You are not calling `req.end()` on your `http request`.**

refer [this documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) on the http module of node.js.

> With **http.request()** one must always call **req.end()** to signify that
>   *you're done with the request* - even if there is no data being written
>   to the request body.

---

on the `req.error` event you are calling `console.alert` which i think should be `console.log`

---

Here is a sample code

```
http = require("http"); 
var options = {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 80,
    method: 'POST'      
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {

    var data = "";
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    });
    res.on('error', function (error) { });
    res.on('end', function () {
        console.log(data)
        req.end();
        console.log(null);
    });

}).on('error', function(e) {

        console.log("Error getting sesame response [%s]", e.message);
        req.end();
        console.log(e.message);
        return

});

req.end();
```