# Error: socket hang up using node v0.12.0

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to perform a very simple HTTP POST with Node:

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
var http = require('http');

var postData = querystring.stringify({
  "source": "XXXX", 
  "target": "XXXX", 
  "create_target": true, 
  "continuous": false
});

var options = { 
  hostname: 'XXXX',
  port: 443,
  path: '/_replicate',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type:':'application/json',
    'Content-Length':Buffer.byteLength(postData)
  } 
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) { 
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) { 
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) { 
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.stack);
});

req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

But the response I get is this:

```
problem with request: Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:215:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:293:23)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:908:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

I'm using node v0.12.0.

---

I have seen these other similar questions on Stackoverflow, but I believe them to be different because:

- [Node.js POST causes [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692580/node-js-post-causes-error-socket-hang-up-code-econnreset) - is an issue POSTing non-ascii characters.
- [nodejs https Error: socket hang up with localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544975/nodejs-https-error-socket-hang-up-with-localhost) - is an issue POSTing to localhost
- [NodeJS HTTP request POST ERROR socket hang up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19787883/nodejs-http-request-post-error-socket-hang-up) - seems to be doing a PUT rather than a POST
- [socket hang up node 0.8.17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304816/socket-hang-up-node-0-8-17) - is not calling req.end()
- [Error: socket hang up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25518967/error-socket-hang-up) - is not stringifying their POST data.
- [node.js socket hang up over https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845752/node-js-socket-hang-up-over-https) - seems to be a version of Node older than v0.12.0 (based on the question date)

Comment: Looking at the node.js code for `createHangUpError()` and when it is called, it appears to be invoked when the socket is being closed before there was any response from the other end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are are making a request to a secure server.  You probably should be using the request method of the https object instead.

In fact, I was able to re-create the problem using the http object and when I simply used the https object I was able to get a response without the socket closing.