# node socket hang up error with http

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, http, request

I followed the [node http document](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) to write a delete request to the local server, but receive the socket hang up error,  similar question I checked are:

- [NodeJS - What does “socket hang up” actually mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995184/nodejs-what-does-socket-hang-up-actually-mean)
- [Error: socket hang up using node v0.12.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813523/error-socket-hang-up-using-node-v0-12-0)

  but no one actually work for my scenario.

I believe it is the code error because I use postman it works for me, following is my code

```
var options = {
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: 3000,
    path: '/accounts/abc'
    method: 'DELETE',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    }
};

var order = {
    "secret": "abc_secret"
};

var content = JSON.stringify(order);
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        console.log('resp: ' + chunk);
    });
});


req.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error('error: ' , err.stack.split("\n"));
});

req.write(content);

req.end();
```

and the errors are:

```
error:  [ 'Error: socket hang up',
  '    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:215:15)',
  '    at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:300:23)',
  '    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:129:20)',
  '    at _stream_readable.js:908:16',
  '    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)' ]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, the request header does not have content length. Therefore, whatever you wrote in the write function will be ignored. Hope this is the root cause.

Comment: yes, both DELETE and POST method need the content length to be set

Answer (score 0):

for me - solved by add Content-Length header.

```
 headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(JSON.stringify(order))
 }
```